# Drop down in nicEditor should be relative to my div

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, nicedit

I have placed nicEditor inside a div which will have its own scroll. Once i click font size in editor the size dropdown list appears according to the window scroll bar.

[image]

I want the position of that dropdown relative to the inside scroll not outside scroll

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.